# S3Client data retrieval intermittently causes lambda function timeout

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, mysql2

The following is a lambda function I'm writing to retrieve a MySQL script from S3 and run it on a specified database.

```
const { S3Client, GetObjectCommand } = require('@aws-sdk/client-s3');
const mysql = require('mysql2/promise');

const s3Client = new S3Client({});

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
    try {
        const dbConfig = {
            user: event.db_user,
            password: event.db_pass,
            host: event.db_host,
            database: event.db_name
        }

        const s3Command = new GetObjectCommand({
            Bucket: process.env.s3_bucket,
            Key: process.env.s3_key
        });

        // Fetch MySQL script from S3
        const scriptResponse = await s3Client.send(s3Command);
        const scriptContent = await scriptResponse.Body.transformToString("utf-8");

        // Connect to database
        const connection = await mysql.createConnection(dbConfig);

        // Run MySQL script
        const [results] = await connection.query(scriptContent);

        // Close database connection
        await connection.end();

        return {
            statusCode: 200,
            body: JSON.stringify(results),
        };
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error:', error);
        return {
            statusCode: 500,
            body: JSON.stringify({ message: error.message }),
        };
    }
};
```

I'm testing the function step by step in AWS Lambda and it mostly times out where I'm fetching my script from S3, i.e. it hits the configuration's timeout setting (up to 5 minutes in my tests). However, it occasionally makes it to the connection step in a fraction of a second, which is what I expect it to do.

There seem to be short streaks where it works as expected but more often than not the run ends in a timeout.

I don't understand why this is happening. The script I'm fetching is relatively long at just under 300k characters and 300KB but it doesn't seem like the size should cause problems here. I tested the function with a tiny SELECT script that fetches one row but the effect is the same.

Comment: Looks like I made a mess of my VPC settings. Now that I've put those in order, the function appears to be running well.